# I need query to provide distinct number of choices

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have eight numbers in my database.
I need to return 28 distinct combinations.
I thought I had the code correct but it returns an infinite number of combinations.

Here is the code.

```
SELECT t1.ID AS Number_1, t2.ID AS Number_2, t3.ID AS Number_3
     , t4.ID AS Number_4, t5.ID AS Number_5, t6.ID AS Number_6 
FROM cTop8 AS t1, cTop8 as t2, cTop8 as t3, cTop8 as t4, cTop8 as t5, cTop8 as t6 
where t2.id<>t1.id and t3.id<>t2.id 
AND t3.id<>t1.id and t4.id<>t3.id 
AND t4.id<>t2.id AND t4.id<>t1.id 
and t5.id<>t4.id AND t5.id<>t3.id 
AND t5.id<>t2.id AND t5.id<>t1.id 
and t6.id<>t5.id AND t6.id<>t4.id 
AND t6.id<>t3.id AND t6.id<>t2.id 
AND t6.id<>t1.id ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: What do you mean by distinct combinations? For the purpose of your question, are `2,3,4,5,6,8` and `2,3,4,5,8,6` the same combination or different combinations?

Comment: They would be the same combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by distinct combinations you mean distinct *sets* of numbers, regardless of their order (in fact, sets are unordered, according to the algebra of sets), then the only fix your script requires is to replace each `<>` with either `>` or `<`, by which I mean that it should be either all `<` or all `>`.

After you switch the comparison symbol, some comparisons will become redundant, and so your query can be simplified. Here is one way to rewrite it:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID AS Number_1,
  t2.ID AS Number_2,
  t3.ID AS Number_3,
  t4.ID AS Number_4,
  t5.ID AS Number_5,
  t6.ID AS Number_6
FROM
  cTop8 AS t1,
  cTop8 AS t2,
  cTop8 AS t3,
  cTop8 AS t4,
  cTop8 AS t5,
  cTop8 AS t6
WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID
  AND t2.ID < t3.ID
  AND t3.ID < t4.ID
  AND t4.ID < t5.ID
  AND t5.ID < t6.ID
;
```

And the output would be exactly 28 rows:

```
Number_1  Number_2  Number_3  Number_4  Number_5  Number_6
--------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------
1         2         3         4         5         6
1         2         3         4         5         7
1         2         3         4         5         8
1         2         3         4         6         7
1         2         3         4         6         8
1         2         3         4         7         8
1         2         3         5         6         7
1         2         3         5         6         8
1         2         3         5         7         8
1         2         3         6         7         8
1         2         4         5         6         7
1         2         4         5         6         8
1         2         4         5         7         8
1         2         4         6         7         8
1         2         5         6         7         8
1         3         4         5         6         7
1         3         4         5         6         8
1         3         4         5         7         8
1         3         4         6         7         8
1         3         5         6         7         8
1         4         5         6         7         8
2         3         4         5         6         7
2         3         4         5         6         8
2         3         4         5         7         8
2         3         4         6         7         8
2         3         5         6         7         8
2         4         5         6         7         8
3         4         5         6         7         8
```

Feel free to keep your `ORDER BY RAND()` if the row order needs to be randomised.